# how to use images as glyphs in holoviews

Tags: data-visualization, bokeh, holoviews

I am using holoviews with the bokeh backend, but for one of the layers, I need to display images at a number of pionts. I've found this bokeh demo (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/image_url.html), which does what I want, but I can't figure out how to get `add_glyph` to work through holoviews.

I'm trying to use holoviews hooks to access the bokeh backend like this:

```
def update_plot(plot, element):
    plot.state.add_glyph(source, image1)

my_plot.opts(hooks=[update_bouys]
```

but I'm not getting my images.

I did get images when I used `hv.render` like below, but that uses the bokeh show, which means I can't overlay it on the rest of my holoviews plots.

```
b = hv.render(my_plot)
b.add_glyph(source, image1)
show(b)
```

If anyone can show me a similar example to the bokeh demo that uses holoviews as a front end, that would be awesome.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HoloViews you'd just use the RGB element: https://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/RGB.html

```py
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

hv.Overlay([hv.RGB.load_image('logo.png', bounds=(2*i,2*i,3*i,3*i))
            for i in range(1,8)])
```

[image]